# Cant access nested object's method

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have this kind of object:

```js
export class Foo {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: boolean;

    get computedProp() {
        return 'some computed data';
    }

    constructor(init?: Partial<Foo>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}

export class Bar {
    propA: any;
    propFoo: Foo;

    constructor(init?: Partial<Bar>) {
        this.propFoo = new Foo();

        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

That I would use this way:

```js
export class MyComponent {

    private _propBar: Bar;
    get propBar() {
        return this._propBar;
    }
    @Input propBar(value: Bar) {
        // value is a json data fetched from api for example
        this._propBar = new Bar(value);
    }

}
```

This is supposed to create a new Bar() object and give me access to all properties but the Foo property is not build correctly and so `computedPro` is not accessible and gives me error in the databinding in html.

I tried the https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer?activeTab=readme package but no good result.

Any Idea? What am I missing?

Thanks

I create this stackblitz to illustrate the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtgu6v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your demo code you have to change your `Bar` constructor should be

```
constructor(init?: Partial<Bar>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
    this.foo=new Foo(init.foo); // you will need to assign new foo object here else it will assign  {propA: 5, propB: 10 } to foo and sum will be undef
  }
```

instead of

```
 constructor(init?: Partial<Bar>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
      }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-77obzc)